# Error when configuring gmp

Tags: c++, c, g++, makefile, gmp

hope this is just a very simple question. Ok, here's what I've done: I wanted to install gmp under my Linux Ubuntu 11.10. I have both g++ and gcc on my system. So I downloaded the latest release from the gmp official site (gmp 5.0.2), extracted it and then, since I need the c++ gmp interface, I simply run:

```
./configure --enable-cxx
```

But it keeps working for a while and then prints out:

```
checking for suitable m4... configure: error: No usable m4 in $PATH or /usr/5bin (see config.log for reasons).
```

Did I do something wrong? Thank you very much!

Matteo

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install m4` and rerun the `./configure`

Comment: Zhenya: put that into an acceptable answer. SO isn't a forum.

Comment: rubenvb: no problem, but is it that big of a deal.

Comment: after 6 years the comment helped me to solve my problem. Thank you @Stackoverflow

Comment: @Matteo Monti - For this question

Comment: @ev-br for the answer

Comment: Now with your help, i am able to proceed further

Comment: where is the m4 source? who makes it/ maintains it? what is m4?, also, is that a typo in the config file? I guess I better read that.

Answer (score 56):

try `sudo apt-get install m4` and rerun the `./configure`

Answer (score 2):

I know this was from 7 years ago, but Im looking at installing gmp5.1.3 from source on an older system right now. I noted the "funny output" `checking for suitable m4... configure: error: No usable m4 in $PATH or /usr/5bin` 5bin hunh? I though it was a typo, and it probably is. On line 27285 of configure script, there is `ac_dummy="$PATH:/usr/5bin"`
that is a shell variable that the script then looks for and doesn't find. in the *nix default FHS, `/usr/5bin` doesn't exist.

the problem with `ac_dummy="$PATH:/usr/5bin"` is that the next few lines are a for  loop searching the $PATH variable + /usr/5bin for m4.
on my system, /usr/sbin is where the m4 files are located, and is not part of the default $PATH variable.

**Fixes:**

you could modify your $PATH variable to include /usr/sbin.

you could modify the configure script to say ac_dummy="$PATH:/usr/sbin"

you could wait 7 years for someone to file a bug report.

depending on age and support of your OS, `sudo apt-get install m4` could also work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, `sudo apt-get install m4` solve this problem.